# Parsing parameters in DAO Update method to whatever type I need

Tags: java, jpa, jdbc, jakarta-ee

I'm creating my first DAO and I have some problems on the update method.

For a field like this in Entity:

```
@Basic
@Column(name = "incheiata", nullable = false)
private Timestamp incheiata;
```

How should my Update look? Right now, my parameters are strings.

Update function header in DAO

```
@Override
public void update(EtapaEntity Etapa, String[] params)
```

I might parse string to timestamp (if it is possible - I haven't look into it yet, but I suppose it is).

But what happens if I have a field like this in my entity:

```
@OneToMany(mappedBy = "persoanaEntity", cascade = CascadeType.REMOVE, orphanRemoval = true)
private Set<Participant> participant = new LinkedHashSet<>();
```

How will my update look? Because I get Strings as arguments, not a Set of whatever entity I need.

So, my question is:

How should my update look in a DAO, when I have multiple data types?

Comment: Normally, you would update the entity directly and let your ORM handle the rest. I'm not really sure what you're trying to do and what you think passing `String[]` would do, or how you would implement that.

Comment: @MarkRotteveel I'm a beginner in Java - I searched online DAO CRUD and this is what I got: https://www.baeldung.com/java-dao-pattern. That's why I'm using that String[]

Comment: You would want to talk to the writer of that tutorial, but it was probably just a simple way of showing a mechanism that updates a java object with a set of values. It would be up to the java developer to decide how to handle each 'string' parameter, the conversions involved and put it into their java object representation - if it is even possible. This is why there are specifications like JPA and JAXB to handle serialization to/from java classes for you and help with that, allowing you to pass around your java object and not string array representations of the data.